# How to find this operators?

Tags: linear-algebra

Find two linear operators $T$ and $U$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $TU=0$ but $UT \neq 0$.

I don't have ideas to solve this. Help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider

$$T(\vec x) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}\vec x, \quad
U(\vec x) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 4 & 5 \\ \end{bmatrix}\vec x.$$

Then, $TU = 0$ but $UT \neq 0$.